# Quantitative convergence for the law of large numbers

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose we have $X_i$ positive random variables iid, with all moments finite.

Do we know how fast $(X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_n)/n$ will go to $E(X_1)$ a.s or in $L^2$ ? Any reference about the convergence rate in the law of large numbers (even not optimal) of such random variables is very welcome.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/203044/rate-of-convergence-in-the-law-of-large-numbers

Comment: The [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) and the [law of the iterated logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_iterated_logarithm) may give you what you want.  You only need the first two moments to be finite